# How can I increase disk space allocated to my VirtualBox VM?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, virtualbox, partitioning, virtual-machine

The basics:
I'm running windows and have a VritualBox VM running Ubuntu 12.04 on top of that. I need to increase the disk space allocated from 8 GB to 12 GB. I'm trying to follow along with [these instructions](https://blogs.oracle.com/fatbloke/entry/growing_your_virtualbox_virtual_disk) but I'm getting stuck on step 2.

Steps I've followed and results:

[image: Step 1 seemed to work ok]

But step 2 seems to falter. I don't see anything more than [image: 1MB unallocated] in order to add to my disk.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you shutdown and restart the guest after making the changes to the drive size?  If you boot the VM from a Linux LiveCD with gPartEd does _it_ see the right size?

Comment: I did restart. no luck. I don't understand the second question at all. How would I boot a vm that's on my windows machine from a liveCD? I don't follow.

Comment: Get an image of a Liunx LiveCD, mount it in the Virtual CD-ROM, and boot from it like you would with a "real" machine. :)

Comment: you just blew my mind... lol